# C# iTextPdf reading Arabic text from PDF in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext, arabic

I'm working on an application to extracts Arabic text from  PDF into string variables, each word comes in reverse order (وسيم Instead of ميسو), and sometimes comes in the correct order but separated characters (م ي س و) similar English characters, but in Arabic, characters are connected together. 
Any solution؟:
I'm using visual studio 2017 C# MVC Application, in windows 10 local, using iTextSharp for reading text from PDF.

in PDF viewer it looks ok,
[image: Text in PDF file]
but when run the following code:

```
private string GetTextFromPDF(string Path)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Path))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
        }
    }

    return text.ToString();
}
```

[image: the result as shown here each keyword written are in reverse order,]

[image: if used for the PDF with English Content it will show correct]

Note: the issue is not only reverse order, if I reversed the order of characters manually (reverse array order) it will show separated text

Comment: for all input files, or only for some ? and does it happen as well if you use iText 7 ? in any case, it's best to upload an example file in order for someone else to be able to debug the issue.

Comment: Is your viewer application supposed to be able to show Arabic text? The conversion from isolated forms to proper initials, medials, and finals does not happen by itself. Your viewer must be able to handle it.

Comment: @ usr2564301 yes, this application is successfully working with MS-Word (.docx) and Text (.txt) documents, all keywords extracted and listed perfectly,

Comment: @blagae , it is same for all PDF Arabic contents input files, currently using itext 5.2.2, I will download and test itext7 package.

Comment: Try other extraction strategies in `TextExtractionStrategy`. It's (alas) a common misconception that text inside a PDF is in a logical order and contains all information to successfully extract it every time from all PDFs. That's why there are different strategies.

Comment: please upload an example file that shows the problem

Comment: I prepared and published application to Azure, 
http://aafss.azurewebsites.net/
go to Administration link, use the following credentials, 
user: nidal2763@hotmail.com
pass: AAss1477.
(with dot in the password) (or you can register new user and login to admin)
download the Arabic testing file from 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao6VZu-nXkAfhCZFJG-NwCGKmvi3
w.txt & w1.pdf
select and input any of them and press Decrypt button, it will take some time then will list keyword and content extracted.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to `MirrorGlyphs`, that's how most of the PDF writers create Arabic PDF's. I've ported [bidi.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/core/bidi.js) to C# to solve this issue:

```
public class BidiResult
{
    public string Text { set; get; }
    public bool IsRtl { set; get; }

    public BidiResult(string text, bool isRtl)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.IsRtl = isRtl;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Ported from https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/core/bidi.js
/// </summary>
public static class Bidi
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Character types for symbols from 0000 to 00FF.
    /// </summary>
    public static string[] BaseTypes = new[] {
                                "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "S", "B", "S", "WS",
                                "B", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN",
                                "BN", "BN", "B", "B", "B", "S", "WS", "ON", "ON", "ET", "ET", "ET", "ON",
                                "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "CS", "ON", "CS", "ON", "EN", "EN", "EN",
                                "EN", "EN", "EN", "EN", "EN", "EN", "EN", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON",
                                "ON", "ON", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L",
                                "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "ON", "ON",
                                "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L",
                                "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L",
                                "L", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "B", "BN",
                                "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN",
                                "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN",
                                "BN", "CS", "ON", "ET", "ET", "ET", "ET", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "L", "ON",
                                "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ET", "ET", "EN", "EN", "ON", "L", "ON", "ON", "ON",
                                "EN", "L", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L",
                                "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L",
                                "L", "ON", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L",
                                "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L",
                                "L", "L", "L", "ON", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L"
                            };

    /// <summary>
    /// Character types for symbols from 0600 to 06FF
    /// </summary>
    public static string[] ArabicTypes = new[] {
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "CS", "AL", "ON", "ON", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM",
                                "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AN", "AN", "AN", "AN", "AN", "AN", "AN", "AN", "AN",
                                "AN", "ET", "AN", "AN", "AL", "AL", "AL", "NSM", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM",
                                "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "ON", "NSM",
                                "NSM", "NSM", "NSM", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL",
                                "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL"
                            };

    public static bool IsOdd(int i)
    {
        return (i & 1) != 0;
    }

    public static bool IsEven(int i)
    {
        return (i & 1) == 0;
    }

    public static int FindUnequal(string[] arr, int start, string value)
    {
        int j;
        var jj = arr.Length;
        for (j = start; j < jj; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[j] != value)
                return j;
        }
        return j;
    }

    public static void SetValues(string[] arr, int start, int end, string value)
    {
        for (var j = start; j < end; ++j)
        {
            arr[j] = value;
        }
    }

    public static char[] ReverseValues(char[] arr, int start, int end)
    {
        var j = end - 1;
        for (var i = start; i < j; ++i, --j)
        {
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static char MirrorGlyphs(char c)
    {
        /*
         # BidiMirroring-1.txt
         0028; 0029 # LEFT PARENTHESIS
         0029; 0028 # RIGHT PARENTHESIS
         003C; 003E # LESS-THAN SIGN
         003E; 003C # GREATER-THAN SIGN
         005B; 005D # LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
         005D; 005B # RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
         007B; 007D # LEFT CURLY BRACKET
         007D; 007B # RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
         00AB; 00BB # LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
         00BB; 00AB # RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
         */
        switch (c)
        {
            case '(':
                return ')';
            case ')':
                return '(';
            case '<':
                return '>';
            case '>':
                return '<';
            case ']':
                return '[';
            case '[':
                return ']';
            case '}':
                return '{';
            case '{':
                return '}';
            case '\u00AB':
                return '\u00BB';
            case '\u00BB':
                return '\u00AB';
            default:
                return c;
        }
    }

    public static BidiResult BidiText(string str, int startLevel)
    {
        var isLtr = true;
        var strLength = str.Length;
        if (strLength == 0)
            return new BidiResult(str, false);

        // get types, fill arrays

        var chars = new char[strLength];
        var types = new string[strLength];
        var oldtypes = new string[strLength];
        var numBidi = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            chars[i] = str[i];

            var charCode = str[i];
            string charType = "L";
            if (charCode <= 0x00ff)
                charType = BaseTypes[charCode];
            else if (0x0590 <= charCode && charCode <= 0x05f4)
                charType = "R";
            else if (0x0600 <= charCode && charCode <= 0x06ff)
                charType = ArabicTypes[charCode & 0xff];
            else if (0x0700 <= charCode && charCode <= 0x08AC)
                charType = "AL";

            if (charType == "R" || charType == "AL" || charType == "AN")
                numBidi++;

            oldtypes[i] = types[i] = charType;
        }

        // detect the bidi method
        //  if there are no rtl characters then no bidi needed
        //  if less than 30% chars are rtl then string is primarily ltr
        //  if more than 30% chars are rtl then string is primarily rtl
        if (numBidi == 0)
        {
            return new BidiResult(str, true);
        }

        if (startLevel == -1)
        {
            if ((strLength / numBidi) < 0.3)
            {
                startLevel = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                isLtr = false;
                startLevel = 1;
            }
        }

        var levels = new int[strLength];

        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            levels[i] = startLevel;
        }

        /*
         X1-X10: skip most of this, since we are NOT doing the embeddings.
         */

        var e = IsOdd(startLevel) ? "R" : "L";
        var sor = e;
        var eor = sor;

        /*
         W1. Examine each non-spacing mark (NSM) in the level run, and change the
         type of the NSM to the type of the previous character. If the NSM is at the
         start of the level run, it will get the type of sor.
         */

        var lastType = sor;
        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            if (types[i] == "NSM")
                types[i] = lastType;
            else
                lastType = types[i];
        }

        /*
         W2. Search backwards from each instance of a European number until the
         first strong type (R, L, AL, or sor) is found.  If an AL is found, change
         the type of the European number to Arabic number.
         */

        lastType = sor;
        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            var t = types[i];
            if (t == "EN")
                types[i] = (lastType == "AL") ? "AN" : "EN";
            else if (t == "R" || t == "L" || t == "AL")
                lastType = t;
        }

        /*
         W3. Change all ALs to R.
         */

        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            var t = types[i];
            if (t == "AL")
                types[i] = "R";
        }

        /*
         W4. A single European separator between two European numbers changes to a
         European number. A single common separator between two numbers of the same
         type changes to that type:
         */

        for (var i = 1; i < strLength - 1; ++i)
        {
            if (types[i] == "ES" && types[i - 1] == "EN" && types[i + 1] == "EN")
                types[i] = "EN";
            if (types[i] == "CS" && (types[i - 1] == "EN" || types[i - 1] == "AN") &&
                types[i + 1] == types[i - 1])
                types[i] = types[i - 1];
        }

        /*
         W5. A sequence of European terminators adjacent to European numbers changes
         to all European numbers:
         */

        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            if (types[i] == "EN")
            {
                // do before
                for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
                {
                    if (types[j] != "ET")
                        break;
                    types[j] = "EN";
                }
                // do after
                for (var j = i + 1; j < strLength; --j)
                {
                    if (types[j] != "ET")
                        break;
                    types[j] = "EN";
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         W6. Otherwise, separators and terminators change to Other Neutral:
         */

        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            var t = types[i];
            if (t == "WS" || t == "ES" || t == "ET" || t == "CS")
                types[i] = "ON";
        }

        /*
         W7. Search backwards from each instance of a European number until the
         first strong type (R, L, or sor) is found. If an L is found,  then change
         the type of the European number to L.
         */

        lastType = sor;
        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            var t = types[i];
            if (t == "EN")
                types[i] = (lastType == "L") ? "L" : "EN";
            else if (t == "R" || t == "L")
                lastType = t;
        }

        /*
         N1. A sequence of neutrals takes the direction of the surrounding strong
         text if the text on both sides has the same direction. European and Arabic
         numbers are treated as though they were R. Start-of-level-run (sor) and
         end-of-level-run (eor) are used at level run boundaries.
         */

        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            if (types[i] == "ON")
            {
                var end = FindUnequal(types, i + 1, "ON");
                var before = sor;
                if (i > 0)
                    before = types[i - 1];
                var after = eor;
                if (end + 1 < strLength)
                    after = types[end + 1];
                if (before != "L")
                    before = "R";
                if (after != "L")
                    after = "R";
                if (before == after)
                    SetValues(types, i, end, before);
                i = end - 1; // reset to end (-1 so next iteration is ok)
            }
        }

        /*
         N2. Any remaining neutrals take the embedding direction.
         */

        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            if (types[i] == "ON")
                types[i] = e;
        }

        /*
         I1. For all characters with an even (left-to-right) embedding direction,
         those of type R go up one level and those of type AN or EN go up two
         levels.
         I2. For all characters with an odd (right-to-left) embedding direction,
         those of type L, EN or AN go up one level.
         */

        for (var i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
        {
            var t = types[i];
            if (IsEven(levels[i]))
            {
                if (t == "R")
                {
                    levels[i] += 1;
                }
                else if (t == "AN" || t == "EN")
                {
                    levels[i] += 2;
                }
            }
            else
            { // isOdd, so
                if (t == "L" || t == "AN" || t == "EN")
                {
                    levels[i] += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         L1. On each line, reset the embedding level of the following characters to
         the paragraph embedding level:

         segment separators,
         paragraph separators,
         any sequence of whitespace characters preceding a segment separator or
         paragraph separator, and any sequence of white space characters at the end
         of the line.
         */

        // don't bother as text is only single line

        /*
         L2. From the highest level found in the text to the lowest odd level on
         each line, reverse any contiguous sequence of characters that are at that
         level or higher.
         */

        // find highest level & lowest odd level

        var highestLevel = -1;
        var lowestOddLevel = 99;
        var ii = levels.Length;
        for (var i = 0; i < ii; ++i)
        {
            var level = levels[i];
            if (highestLevel < level)
                highestLevel = level;
            if (lowestOddLevel > level && IsOdd(level))
                lowestOddLevel = level;
        }

        // now reverse between those limits

        for (var level = highestLevel; level >= lowestOddLevel; --level)
        {
            // find segments to reverse
            var start = -1;
            ii = levels.Length;
            for (var i = 0; i < ii; ++i)
            {
                if (levels[i] < level)
                {
                    if (start >= 0)
                    {
                        chars = ReverseValues(chars, start, i);
                        start = -1;
                    }
                }
                else if (start < 0)
                {
                    start = i;
                }
            }
            if (start >= 0)
            {
                chars = ReverseValues(chars, start, levels.Length);
            }
        }

        /*
         L3. Combining marks applied to a right-to-left base character will at this
         point precede their base character. If the rendering engine expects them to
         follow the base characters in the final display process, then the ordering
         of the marks and the base character must be reversed.
         */

        // don't bother for now

        /*
         L4. A character that possesses the mirrored property as specified by
         Section 4.7, Mirrored, must be depicted by a mirrored glyph if the resolved
         directionality of that character is R.
         */

        // don't mirror as characters are already mirrored in the pdf

        // Finally, return string

        var result = string.Empty;
        ii = chars.Length;
        for (var i = 0; i < ii; ++i)
        {
            var ch = chars[i];
            if (ch != '<' && ch != '>')
                result += ch;
        }

        return new BidiResult(result, isLtr);
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
public static string GetTextFromPDF(string path)
{
    var reader = new PdfReader(path);
    var text = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        var data = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
        text.Append(Bidi.BidiText(data, 1).Text);
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I tested this class with my code, and it works with no errors, but still, the result is not what is expected, yes it reversed the characters order to the correct order but three issues still there, first characters comes separated like English characters and this is not how Arabic works, second, the words (in one sentence) still come in reverse order, and third the sentences in a paragraph also comes in reverse order

Comment: I tested your `w1.pdf` with the above method and this is its result: " السبت األحد اثنين السبت األحد اثنين السبت األحد اثنين". It needs more work for the "لا", but it works fine and its characters are not separated.

Comment: @VahidN did you find any way to fix "لا". I have the same  problem in farsi